# How to add a group to navigation drawer programmatically

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer in my android app. I can add groups and items to it by mean of XML, however, I need to add new groups to it programmatically.

For example, I have this XML:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_camara" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_gallery" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_manage" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>
```

How can I do it if that group has no items and I need to add them by code?

If I use:

```
Menu sistemas = navigationView.getMenu();
sistemas.add(Menu.FIRST, 1, 0, "Prueba");
```

The item is added as a menu below all options, not as a group.

Regards,
Jaime

Comment: I suggest you all items programatically, as suggested in [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/).

Comment: `sistemas.addSubMenu` ? is it what you want to do?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `NavigationView`.  I looked at the code for `NavigationView` and it is not dynamic.  It uses the menu resource to create the view at initialization and basically ignores it after that.  If you want to do anything dynamic you'll need to look for another solution beyond `NavigationView`.  Fortunately, there are plenty of nav drawers on GitHub.  I rolled my own using `android.support.design.internal.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout`.

Comment: may be this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722566/dynamic-adding-item-to-navigationview-in-android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My best suggestion if you want to stick to NavigationView is to do the following:

Set up your XML to contain any groups you think you need to add dynamically and set them to invisible:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <group android:id="@+id/main_group">
         <item android:id="@+id/nav_camara"
             android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
             android:title="Import" />
         <item android:id="@+id/nav_gallery" 
             android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
             android:title="Gallery" />
         <item android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow" 
             android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
             android:title="Slideshow" />
         <item android:id="@+id/nav_manage" 
             android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
             android:title="Tools" />
    </group>
    <group android:visible="false" android:id="@+id/second_group">

    </group>
    <group android:visible="false" android:id="@+id/third_group">

    </group>
</menu>
```

Then when you need to show them or add dynamic options for these groups:

```
      Menu menu = mNavView.getMenu();

      // Add items to the second group, and set to visible
      menu.add(R.id.second_group, 1, 100, "Item 1");
      menu.add(R.id.second_group, 2, 200, "Item 2");
      menu.add(R.id.second_group, 3, 300, "Item 3");
      menu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.second_group, true, true);
      menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.second_group, true);

      // Add items to the third group, and set to visible
      menu.add(R.id.third_group, 4, 400, "Item 1");
      menu.add(R.id.third_group, 5, 500, "Item 2");
      menu.add(R.id.third_group, 6, 600, "Item 3");
      menu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.third_group, true, true);
      menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.third_group, true);
```

Just make sure when you add your items, the item Id's are different and the order in category are the actual order in the whole menu of dynamic items.

Comment: I have done it and the option is added, however, when I click in it, the background does not change to gray reflecting it is selected, as the other group items behave. Do I need to do something else? for example, to assign a click handler or whatever.

Comment: @jstuardo if each group needs to be checkable just add `android:checkableBehavior="single"` to those which need it in the xml definition of the menu

Comment: No luck. I have set that attribute to group tag, and onNavigationItemSelected is even being called, however, the item shows no selection. When I click on the predefined group, the onNavigationItemSelected is also called and the item shows  correctly with gray brackground.

Comment: @jstuardo sorry to have misled you please see the update above, you should do this in your code

Comment: trying this, but it keep adding the MenuItem to the end of the NavDraw and not to the Hidden group in the middle of the Drawer =/