# Set item visible xml with java coding android studio

Tags: android, xml

I have xml code like this, and i want to set some item visible to be true with coding in java (android studio), what code should i type?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="HOME" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_login"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_login"
        android:title="LOGIN" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:title="LOGOUT"
        android:visible="false"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_category"
        android:title="CATEGORY"
        android:visible="false"/>
</group>
```

Comment: you can add and remove menu item programatically

Comment: can you give some example? im still learning thx before

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31722855/6541643 refer this

Comment: thx but that is not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

If you want to hide "nav_login"

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_login);
    item.setVisible(false);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you share your crash log and activity file

Answer (score 0):

You can use it after setting up NavigationView

```
 navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_login).setVisible(false);
```