# How to add MenuItem to NavigationView with Icon and Title dynamically in Android?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am using Navigation Drawer in my Android app, on that showing different MenuItems.

I want to add menuItem dynamically. For that menuItem, I want to set Icon and Title dynamically. I want to set ImageUrl from server in Icon.

Bellow is the code I tried.

```
Menu menu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem item = menu.add(groupId, menuItemId, Order, "Menu Item 1 Title");
item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_some_menu_item_icon);
```

But it is not working, kindly help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamic adding item to NavigationView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722566/dynamic-adding-item-to-navigationview-in-android)

Comment: Are you actually typing the word `Order`? It won't work then, you need to put an integer there. Replace `Order` with `0` and it works for me. Also, check your `groupId` and `menuItemId`.